# Unity wont show me my serialized fields for game state on the inspector window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

Unity's console its giving me the next errors:

1. error CS1061: Type 'UnityEngine.Texture' does not contain a definition for 'color' and no extention method 'color' of type 'UnityEngine.Texture' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
2. error CS1061: Type 'UnityEngine.Texture' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extention method 'text' of type 'UnityEngine.Texture' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

any idea what it could be? here's the code...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameState : MonoBehaviour {

private bool gameStarted = false;
[SerializeField]
private Texture gameStateText;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject player;
[SerializeField]
private BirdMovement birdMovement;
[SerializeField]
private FollowCamera followCamera;
private float restartDelay = 3f;
private float restartTimer;
private PlayerMovement playerMovement;
private PlayerHealth playerHealth;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Cursor.visible = false;

    playerMovement = player.GetComponent<PlayerMovement> ();
    playerHealth = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth> ();

    // Prevent the player from moving at the start of the game
    playerMovement.enabled = false;

    // Prevent the bird from moving at the start of the game
    birdMovement.enabled = false;

    // Prevent the follow camera from moving to its game position
    followCamera.enabled = false;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    // If the game is not started and the player presses the space bar...
    if (gameStarted == false && Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space)) {

        // ...start the game.
        StartGame();

    }

    // If the player is no longer alive...
    if (playerHealth.alive == false) {

        // ...end the game.
        EndGame();

        // ...increment a timer to count up to restarting...
        restartTimer = restartTimer + Time.deltaTime;

        // ...and if it reashes the restart delay...
        if (restartTimer >= restartDelay) {

            // ...then reload the currently loaded scene.
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);


        }

    }

}

private void StartGame () {

    // Set the game state
    gameStarted = true;

    // Remove the start text
    gameStateText.color = Color.clear;

    // Allow the player to move
    playerMovement.enabled = true;

    // Allow the bird to move
    birdMovement.enabled = true;

    // Allow the camera to mover 
    followCamera.enabled = true;

}

private void EndGame () {
    // Set the game state
    gameStarted = false;

    // Show the game over text
    gameStateText.color = Color.white;
    gameStateText.text = "Game Over!";

    // Remove the player from the game
    player.SetActive (false);
}

}
```

Comment: It's not showing due to the compiler errors. `gameStateText` is a `Texture` but your treating it like a `Text` component. Replace `Texture gameStateText` with `Text gameStateText` at the top of your script.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked !, I must had typed Text or something similar and pressed enter and  MonoDevelop had completed it by putting Texture... was desperate, gonna make sure to triple check next time.